# how do I get my image list inside a hitbox?

Tags: python, css, pygame

ok so I found out my collision was based on this square and its not colliding
with my image because my image isnt inside the square OR the hitbox you can call it it is there a way to put my player inside the hitbox so it can work good

this is my player class [Video Of My Game](https://gyazo.com/40346ebf6c8d6a5f39a8149c4a691284) I know the problem but I just don't know how to move my player without moving the hitbox inside the hitbox so I could collide good

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height  = height
        self.width = width
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")
        self.lefts = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0001.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0004.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0005.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0006.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0007.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0008.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png")
         ]
        self.rights = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-50.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-51.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-52.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-53.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-54.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-55.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-56.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-57.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-58.png")
         ]
        self.rights = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.rights]
        self.lefts = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.lefts]
        self.stand = pygame.transform.scale(self.stand,(self.stand.get_width()*4,self.stand.get_height()*4))
        self.bo_index = 0
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.stans_index = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.direction = "standing"
        self.rect = pygame.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width, height)

    def draw(self):

        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,0), self.rect)
        if self.direction == "left":
             window.blit(self.lefts[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
             self.anim_index += 1
             if self.anim_index == len(self.lefts):
                 self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.rights[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.rights):
                self.anim_index = 0

        else:
            window.blit(self.stand,self.rect)
```

my full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
slash = pygame.image.load("slash_03.png")
stand = pygame.image.load("bunny2_stand.png")


lefts = [pygame.image.load("Sprite-0001.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0004.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0005.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0006.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0007.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0008.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png")

         ]


stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")


rights = [pygame.image.load("Sprite-50.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-51.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-52.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-53.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-54.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-55.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-56.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-57.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-58.png")


         ]

class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 10
        self.slash = pygame.image.load("slash_03.png")
    def draw(self,win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

# the enemy
class enes:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)







# color for enems
green = (63, 190, 22)
enems1 = enes(350,259,50,50, green)
florida = [enems1]

# player class

class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height  = height
        self.width = width
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")
        self.lefts = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0001.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0004.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0005.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0006.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0007.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0008.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png")
         ]
        self.rights = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-50.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-51.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-52.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-53.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-54.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-55.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-56.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-57.png"),
         pygame.image.load("Sprite-58.png")
         ]
        self.rights = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.rights]
        self.lefts = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.lefts]
        self.stand = pygame.transform.scale(self.stand,(self.stand.get_width()*4,self.stand.get_height()*4))
        self.bo_index = 0
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.stans_index = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.direction = "standing"
        self.rect = pygame.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width, height)

    def draw(self):

        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,0), self.rect)
        if self.direction == "left":
             window.blit(self.lefts[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
             self.anim_index += 1
             if self.anim_index == len(self.lefts):
                 self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.rights[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.rights):
                self.anim_index = 0

        else:
            window.blit(self.stand,self.rect)








# platforms
class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,plat.get_width(), plat.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.plat,(self.plat.get_width()//2,self.plat.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.plat,self.rect)

# Coins
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,coinss.get_width(), coinss.get_height())
        self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.coinss,(self.coinss.get_width()//2,self.coinss.get_height()//2))
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.coinss,self.rect)


# Floor
class floor:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
score = 0
text = font.render('Gold  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)

# enemy
Sfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
Kills = 0
Stext = Sfont.render('Kills  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRectS = Stext.get_rect()  
textRectS.center = (400, 100)


# fps
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (63, 190, 22)
Blue = (22, 190, 175)
white = (240, 240, 240)

# define the enemy player coin classes
playerman = player(140,350,40,50, Blue)
enemy1 = platform(150,390,190,10, Green)
enemy2 = platform(300,310,190,10, Green)
enemy3 = platform(80,260,190,10, Green)
enemy4 = platform(250,180,190,10, Green)
enemy5 = platform(490,120,190,10, Green)
enemy6 = platform(-50,100,190,10, Green)
enemy7 = platform(180,50,190,10, Green)
platforms = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,enemy5,enemy6,enemy7]

# coin class
coin1 = coin(180,320,150,150, Green)
coin2 = coin(350,250,50,50, Green)
coin3 = coin(150,200,50,50, Green)


Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3]

# floor class
floor1 = floor(-1000,490,9999,50, white)
flories = [floor1]

#main loop
bullets = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y += playerman.speed
        for enes in florida:
            enes.y += playerman.speed




    if playerman.y > 450:

        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y -= playerman.fall
        for enes in florida:
            enes.y -= playerman.fall





    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    playerman.direction = "standing"

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:     
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x -= bullet.speed 
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        if len(bullets) < 2:  
            bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed
            for enes in florida:
                enes.x += playerman.speed


    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed
            for enes in florida:
                enes.x -= playerman.speed




    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False
        collide = False
        for platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = platform.rect.right


            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()  
                    textRect.center = (100, 40)





        for floor in flories:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = floor.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor.rect.right






            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 490:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 490 - playerman.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0


    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False

    window.fill((74, 107, 104))
    enems1.draw()
    window.blit(Stext,textRectS)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for platform in platforms:
        platform.draw()
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()
    playerman.draw()
    for floor in flories:
        floor.draw()



    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: First, please proof read your question. I have a hard time understanding it. But you could try to draw the rects on the screen to check what their hitboxes look like. For that you can use `pygame.draw.rect`

Comment: my problem is, is that my collision isnt colliding with my platform images Right take a look at the [video]( https://gyazo.com/cdf153daf235592a5af96b7c80d92c99)  it collides but when I move on the right side of my platform you could see that on the vid its colliding on the air not on the platform

Comment: That doesn't change my advice. Please try drawing the rects.

Comment: alr I will do so

Comment: You could also try changing `self.width = width` to `self.width = self.platforms.get_width()` so the hitbox of the platform is the same as the image, you would have to move the line 'self.width =' below `self.platforms=`

Comment: ``` self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()*5,self.platforms.get_height()*5))```  change the self.platfroms to self.width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class enemy:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.platforms = pygame.image.load("level5.png") #get the image so can find width
       self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()*5,self.platforms.get_height()*5))
       self.width = self.platforms.get_width() #get the width of the image
       self.color = color
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
       self.anim_index = 0
       self.rect = self.platforms.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)) 
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, self.platforms.get_width(), self.platforms.get_height())
```

the image and the hitbox(the part where you can stand on) were two different sizes, you want them to be the same. so instead of giving the width to the platform. calculate the width from the image so you know they are both the same size

---

if you add a `pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,0), self.rect)` in the draw method of enemy, then you can see exactly where the player can stand or not, then we can see if the problem is the image, or the collision

```
def draw:
     self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
     pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,0,0),self.rect)
     window.blit(self.platforms,self.rect) #making sure that you draw the image on top of the square
```

Comment: I made the hitbox with my platform to collide each part I am kinda confused right now it only does that if I have an image platform can you like farther explain i dont get it I don;t know how my image and hitbox are defferent size even tho I made it so it is the same as it is

Comment: I have tried what u gave me but idk it doesnt seem to work how do I calculate  sorry if I am asking to much questions

Comment: @HabibIsmail Ive also noticed that you have `self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, self.platforms.get_width(), self.platforms.get_height())` at the bottom so my answer didnt do anything. Did you add what Meglang said to add, so, you can see where the player can stand. Also dont apologize for asking questions. this website is literally about asking questions

Comment: yah i did what he said it shows  [Video](https://gyazo.com/ccd0019102ff0b464fd9886701a382fc)big black boxes I asssume those are the collisions? here is what I [image](https://gyazo.com/f1f5ddbb05daa4eca4a9bd76e08dc8ff)

Comment: @HabibIsmail awesome, yes the black box is what the player can stand on, just one more thing, to really understand whats going draw both the black box and the image, its in the answer

Comment: does seem to work I draw it and changed the size on my enemy1 = enemy(150,390,20,20,White)
enemy2 = enemy(350,300,20,20,White)
enemy3 = enemy(10,260,20,20,White)
and then I dont think the black thing is where the player stands on because I am still standing on mid air https://gyazo.com/7c7a93a1b4963f2c70206b8b3b2b5e54

Comment: @HabibIsmail Ok, that looks, good, dont worry, that wasnt a solutions, it wasnt meant to work. but if you do the same black box for the player, i reckon you will find it is bigger like the platform, the black box is where the player can stand (whether the images or the collision code is broken) you want that black box to be the same size the platform, the best way to do this, is to open the image in what you used to make it and crop the top so its just the platform

Comment: or, change `self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,self.platforms.get_width(), self.platforms.get_height())` to self.rect = pygame.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width, height) and change it manually until it looks about right

Comment: Oooh I understand

Comment: I updated the question I know the problem its in the player hitbox is there a way I can move the player inside the hitbox collision I updated the question like get the player image list in the same position as my hitbox collision

Comment: like the yellow part is whats colliding and not the player image if I Can get that image inside the player frame like move it there without resizing the player that could fix the problem but idk how to put a list of images inside the hitbox

Comment: @HabibIsmail if you right click on one of the images you are using for the player, go on properties and on the details tab, you can see how big the image is. use the the size as the width and height for the player, then it will cover the image, but be too big, it will start where it is now and end at the bottom right of the player, so you can stand, but not ideal

Comment: idealy, you will need to crop the image in a image editor so the edges are the edges of the player